# WBF (Windows Biometric Framework) use a separate sdk/library for matching fingerprints

Tags: fingerprint, biometrics

We need to do biometric authentication as part of our current security infrastructure. Currently we have our own application which upon login asks the user to present his fingerprint (to a scanner connected to his USB port, we are using Nitgen Hamter IV), the fingerprint is then converted to a text representation (using Nitgen's SDK) and then sent to our server via a REST call. The server matches this FP to the registered FPs in the central repository and accordingly logs in the user.

Now, we have a requirement to use a machine's native (or clients existing Biometric sensors) sensors for the same. By native I mean the swipe sensor we see on HP Laptops (powered by Validity/Synaptics). So we thought a better way to do so would be to do all the talking via Window's WBF framework. I have been reading the docs and am a little confused.

Now, I know that I can get the data using WBF into WinBio's BIR format (using WinBioCaptureSample function). This format from what I hear is CBEFF compliant. My question is how do I serialize/store/match this record at my server end? My server doesn't understand WBF. Is there a third party SDK that can take WBF generated BIR's and do the comparison/matching? Basically I want to use WBF just for capturing the fingerprint, and need a way to store and match these fingerprints at an external server.

(Ex. Can Verifinger SDK or Griaule SDK achieve this for me?)

Answer (score 0):

Very little info out there. This isn't really an answer for you but might be helpful.

I was also looking into this for a similar purpose a while back (on hold for now). I was looking at using a third party library completely (currently looking at VeriFinger by neurotechnology.com), however the licensing gets a little pricey for our end users when they have a lot of (100+) workstations.

Then I then ran across the WBF API, so now I am thinking about using the WBF to capture the fingerprint and just use the third party identification library (engine) for the matching and possibly the storage. That means just a license for the matching engine and not all of the clients.

Depending on the identification engine you use, it may be able to take the full image from the scan or just a template. I'm pretty sure you can get the actual image from the WBF API and then pass that to your back end system to create the template or do the identification - but I can't find the API calls for how I thought you could get the image from the WBF API right now.

Comment: Hi Toby, I believe you are facing exactly the same issues. For now I am looking at:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f6f09403-e0b6-4977-b697-d5aabeb5b8ff/how-to-convert-winbiobir-data-into-image-using-windows-biometric-framework?forum=wdk

This might get us the image from BIR. What I am more interested in is using BIR (which is CBEFF compliant) as it is and passing to veriifnger/griaule (also supporting CBEFF as per there docs). Maybe someone from their dev team might read this post and help us out.

Comment: I found the NT support people to be very responsive via email - even though I was just evaluating the product - so you might send them an email and see if they can use CBEFF directly.